# A variable number (n) of nested for-loops where n is the number of class attributes in Python?

Tags: python, loops, oop, recursion, nested-loops

I am trying to set up an exhaustive search of iterations where each permutation of attributes are tested with numbers between 0 and 50.

I have several classes with varying numbers of attributes and I'm trying to find an ubiquitous solution to apply that doesn't involve tailoring to each individual class' number of attributes.

I have seen several solutions that have tried to use recursion but they don't appear to make sense/ answer my question,.

```
class test():
    
    def __init__(self, a, b ,c):
        #3 attributes, max range 10, 1000 iterations needed
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c
        
        
    def recurse(self):
        if self.a = 10:
            return self
        else:
            #Do something
```

I'm trying to set up something like the following but this still relies upon knowing the number of attributes of each class.

Comment: These are instance attributes. You could programatically ge these attributes off the instance by using `list(vars(instance))`

Comment: That's really useful to know, but how would I then iterate through all of these in a nested fashion?

Comment: itertools.combinations probably. Avoid recursion in python, if an iterable can do the job. We may need more of a [mcve] to say more.

Comment: I've just tried working with itertools.combinations but I don't think it will be able to work. Essentially, given a class of variable number of attributes. I need a list of the same length of numbers within a specific range.